# How to convert word to numerics using huggingface or spacy or any python based workflow

Tags: python, nltk, spacy, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have lot of text which has the counting in words as well in different languages (different datasets but one data has one language so no mixing of language).

like

```
I have one apple 
I have two kids
```

and
I want it to convert as

```
I have 1 apple
I have 2 kids
```

Is it possible to change that to the numbers / integers using huggingface or any ? or any suggestion for such problem would help! English Dutch French German supporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with different versions of different libraries. With my tests fo far, I found out this as working perfectly for most of the cases.

[words to numerics](https://github.com/allo-media/text2num)

This is the better solution and covers English French German Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some external package to easly accomplish this. Please take a look at this one https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

Comment: That I assume is only in English and I am handling several other languages with different datasets.

Comment: you didn't say what languages you need to support. Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/word2number-i18n/ It supports English, French, Portugues, Russian, Slovak, Spanish